# Center lock icon indicator for ViewPager

Tags: android, android-viewpager

I'm making an app in which I need to have an horizontal scroll view with several `Fragments` and an indicator.

The indicator of the current item must be centered horizontally, the `Fragments` can be selected by swiping the `Fragments` themselves or by scrolling and snapping the indicators or by clicking directly on one indicator (see pictures below).

It seems that the standard way to do that is to use a `ViewPager` along with a `PagerTabStrip`, but I cannot find how I can have this center-lock behaviour with the `PagerTabStrip`.

Any suggestion?

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: PagerTabStrip doesn't have all the behaviors you want, you'll have to make something custom. I would look at the PagerSlidingTabStrip library and see if anything there gives you any insight on how to create yours. https://github.com/astuetz/PagerSlidingTabStrip

Comment: Most likely, you will need to create your own indicator, using `PagerTabStrip`, `PagerSlidingTabStrip`, and the indicators in the ViewPagerIndicator library as starting points.

Comment: Yes, it seems that I'll have to implement my own solution. I'll post it here as soon as I'm done.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I forked Andreas Stuetz's [PagerSlidingTabStrip](https://github.com/astuetz/PagerSlidingTabStrip)
to implement that [PagerSlidingIndicator](https://github.com/julj/PagerSlidingIndicator).